State Machine role failing to create using SAM template
I'm trying to build a nested stack, but right now I just want to get this singular template working. Not sure why the role is failing to create, as I have all the necessary values filled out. I tried commenting on the extra policies, after reading that can cause interference, but have run this with those commented sections uncommented.
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  SourceBucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the bucket used to store the repo.
  GlueAssetsBucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the bucket used to store glue runtime logs, temp files, etc
  SaphanaGlueConnection:
    Type: String
    Description: Connection from glue to SAP HANA
  GlueJobRoleArn:
    Type: String
    Description: ARN of the IAM Role for Glue Jobs
  # StateMachineExecutionRoleArn:
  #   Type: String
  #   Description: ARN of the IAM Role for Step Function execution

Resources:
  StateMachineExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties: 
      RoleName: !Sub 'SMExecutionRole-${AWS::StackName}'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement: 
          - Effect: 'Allow'
            Principal:
              Service: 'states.amazonaws.com'
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess'
        # - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole'
      # Policies:
      #   - PolicyName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-StepFunctionPolicy'
      #     PolicyDocument:
      #       Version: '2012-10-17'
      #       Statement:
      #         - Effect: 'Allow'
      #           Action:
      #             - 'glue:StartJobRun'
      #             - 'glue:GetJobRun'
      #             - 'glue:GetJobRuns'
      #             - 'glue:BatchStopJobRun'
      #           Resource: '*'

  DevHanaS3GoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsGlueJob:
    Type: 'AWS::Glue::Job'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'dev-hana-s3-gold-tdp-all-sales-openperiods-${AWS::StackName}'
      Role: !Ref GlueJobRoleArn
      Command:
        Name: 'glueetl'
        ScriptLocation: !Sub 's3://${SourceBucketName}/TDP/jobs/tdp-all-sales/glue/dev-hana-s3-gold-tdp-all-sales-openperiods.py'
        PythonVersion: '3'
      DefaultArguments:
        "--enable-metrics": "true"
        "--enable-spark-ui": "true"
        "--spark-event-logs-path": !Sub "s3://${GlueAssetsBucketName}/sparkHistoryLogs-${AWS::StackName}/"
        "--enable-job-insights": "false"
        "--enable-observability-metrics": "true"
        "--enable-glue-datacatalog": "true"
        "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true"
        "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable"
        "--job-language": "python"
        "--TempDir": !Sub "s3://${GlueAssetsBucketName}/temporary-${AWS::StackName}/"
      Connections:
        Connections:
          - !Ref SaphanaGlueConnection
      MaxRetries: 0
      Timeout: 2880
      WorkerType: 'G.1X'
      NumberOfWorkers: 10
      GlueVersion: '4.0'
      ExecutionClass: 'STANDARD'

  DevS3RedshiftGoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsGlueJob:
    Type: 'AWS::Glue::Job'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'dev-s3-redshift-gold-tdp-all-sales-openperiods-${AWS::StackName}'
      Role: !Ref GlueJobRoleArn
      Command:
        Name: 'glueetl'
        ScriptLocation: !Sub 's3://${SourceBucketName}/TDP/jobs/tdp-all-sales/glue/dev-s3-redshift-gold-tdp-all-sales-openperiods.py'
        PythonVersion: '3'
      DefaultArguments:
        "--enable-metrics": "true"
        "--enable-spark-ui": "true"
        "--spark-event-logs-path": !Sub "s3://${GlueAssetsBucketName}/sparkHistoryLogs-${AWS::StackName}/"
        "--enable-job-insights": "false"
        "--enable-observability-metrics": "true"
        "--enable-glue-datacatalog": "true"
        "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "true"
        "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable"
        "--job-language": "python"
        "--TempDir": !Sub "s3://${GlueAssetsBucketName}/temporary-${AWS::StackName}/"
      Connections:
        Connections:
          - !Ref SaphanaGlueConnection
      MaxRetries: 0
      Timeout: 2880
      WorkerType: 'G.1X'
      NumberOfWorkers: 10
      GlueVersion: '4.0'
      ExecutionClass: 'STANDARD'

############### STEP FUNCTIONS ###############
  GoldTdpAllSalesDailyStepFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'gold-tdp-all-sales-daily-${AWS::StackName}'
      DefinitionUri: 
        Bucket: !Ref SourceBucketName
        Key: 'TDP/jobs/tdp-all-sales/step_functions/gold-tdp-all-sales-daily.json'
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        DevHanaS3GoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsJob: !Ref DevHanaS3GoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsGlueJob
        DevS3RedshiftGoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsJob: !Ref DevS3RedshiftGoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsGlueJob
      Events:
        ScheduledExecution:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Description: "Schedule for running the gold-tdp-all-sales-daily Step Function"
            Schedule: "cron(0 6 * * ? *)"
            Enabled: true
            Name: !Sub 'gold-tdp-all-sales-daily-${AWS::StackName}'
      Role: !GetAtt StateMachineExecutionRole.Arn
      Type: STANDARD
      Logging:
        Level: "OFF"
        IncludeExecutionData: false
      Tracing:
        Enabled: false
      Tags:
        StackName: !Ref AWS::StackName

Outputs:
  DevHanaS3GoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsJobName:
    Description: "Name of the Dev HANA to S3 Gold TDP All Sales Openperiods Glue Job"
    Value: !Ref DevHanaS3GoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsGlueJob

  DevS3RedshiftGoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsJobName:
    Description: "Name of the Dev S3 to Redshift Gold TDP All Sales Openperiods Glue Job"
    Value: !Ref DevS3RedshiftGoldTdpAllSalesOpenperiodsGlueJob

  GoldTdpAllSalesDailyStepFunctionArn:
    Description: "ARN of the Gold TDP All Sales Daily Step Function"
    Value: !Ref GoldTdpAllSalesDailyStepFunction


what's the error and what's the definition?

Then Name was too long. Wasn't seeing in the git workflow console, but it was showing up in the CloudFormation console.
